# Unity 5 Sprite Editor not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5 to create a puzzle game.

From an article that I've read, it says there that I have to use the sprite editor. But in my Unity, I can't find the Sprite Editor.

So I can't progress on the things that I need to do because of this.

How do I find it? It doesn't also appear in the Windows Tab and Inspector Window.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this will help, but I had this same issue and it didn't matter whether I changed my package manager to all packages or in project i couldn't see the Sprite editor.
I put my package manager setting to in project and closed unity. after reopening unity i then changed that setting to all packages, it refreshed and i could now see the 2D sprite package and install it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a texture and set its type to Sprite (2D and UI) or advanced.

[image]

Also, pay attention to the Sprite Mode, if you want an atlas use Multiple.  This will allow you to draw multiple regions denoting individual sprites in the texture.  You can also adjust the borders individually for 9-slice scaling.